# A scalable Graph method for finding cliques for complete connected components PySpark

Tags: pyspark, graph, networkx, scale, connected-components

I'm trying to split GraphFrame connectedComponent output for each component to have a sub-group for each complete connected, meaning all vertices are connected to each other. the following sketch will help demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

I'm using NetworkX method in order to achive it as following

```
def create_subgroups(edges,components, key_name = 'component'):
  
  # joining the edges to enrich component id
  sub_components = edges.join(components,[(edges.dst == components.id) | (edges.src == components.id)]).select('src','dst',key_name).drop_duplicates()
  
  # caching the table using temp table
  sub_components = save_temp_table(sub_components,f'inner_sub_{key_name}s', zorder = [key_name])
  
  schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("index",LongType(),True), \
    StructField("id",StringType(),True), \
  ])

  # applying pandas udf to enrich each vertices with the new component id
  sub_components = sub_components.groupby(key_name).applyInPandas(pd_create_subgroups, schema).where('id != "not_connected"').drop_duplicates()
  
  # joining the output and mulitplying each vertices by the time of sub-groups were found
  components = components.join(sub_components,'id','left')
  components = components.withColumn(key_name,when(col('index').isNull(),col(key_name)).otherwise(concat(col(key_name),lit('_'),concat('index')))).drop('index')
  
  return components
```

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.clique import find_cliques

def pd_create_subgroups(pdf):
    # building the graph
    gnx = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(pdf,'src','dst')
    
    # removing one degree nodes
    outdeg = gnx.degree()
    to_remove = [n[0] for n in outdeg if n[1] == 1]
    gnx.remove_nodes_from(to_remove)
        
    bic = list(find_cliques(gnx))

    if len(bic)<=2:
      return pd.DataFrame(data = {"index":[-1],"id":["not_connected"]})

    
    res = {
      "index":[],
      "id":[]
          }

    ind = 0
    for i in bic:
      
      if len(i)<3:
        continue
        
      for id in i:
        res['index'] = res['index'] + [ind]
        res['id'] = res['id'] + [id]
      ind += 1
    
    return pd.DataFrame(res)
```

```
# creating sub-components if necessary 
subgroups = create_subgroups(edges,components, key_name = 'component')
```

My problem is that there's a very large component containing 80% of the vertices causing very slow performance of the clusters. I've been trying to use labelPropagation to create smaller groups but it wouldn't do the trick. it has split it in a way that isn't suitable causing a split of vertices that should have been in the same groups.

Here's the cluster usage when it reaches the pandas_udf part
[image]

Comment: have you looked onto graphframes?

Comment: @AlexOtt as I wrote above I've been using GF. but it doesn't support all functions I need to solve this issue.

Comment: I've found out there are many one-degree edges or two vertices sub-groups. filtering them out has improved performance dramatically.

Comment: ah, sorry - missed that keyword :-)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by separating vertices into N groups, pulling all edges for each vertice in the group, and calculating the sub-group using the find_cliques method.